# I am looking for NPM archives for an old dependence

Tags: npm, dependencies, archive

Hello: I have an old medical test management platform, which uses dependence called: Promised information. I have no way of knowing what it is used for, at least I would like to know its usefulness before deleting it and possibly replacing it with another dependence. I would like to know if there is the possibility of finding archives of old dependence unpublished

NPM registry link: https://registry.npmjs.org/promise-information

- search on GitHub and Gitlab
- search on Google and DuckduckGo in any case all the first pages